# EXC_BAD_ACCESS objective-c block

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, block

I run this code inside my `viewDidLoad` method to fetch data from Firebase to put it in a `UIPageViewController`

```
@interface MapViewController () <RoutesPageDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) RoutesPageViewController *routesPageViewController;
@property (weak, nonatomic) FIRFirestore *db;
@end

@implementation MapViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.db = [FIRFirestore firestore];

    for (UIViewController *obj in self.childViewControllers) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[RoutesPageViewController class]]) {
            self.routesPageViewController = (RoutesPageViewController *)obj;
            self.routesPageViewController.routesPageDelegate = self;
        }
    }

    FIRCollectionReference *routesRef = [self.db collectionWithPath:@"routes"];
    [routesRef getDocumentsWithCompletion:^(FIRQuerySnapshot * _Nullable snapshot, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            // TODO: handle error
        } else {
            NSMutableArray<RouteModel*> *routes = [NSMutableArray array];

            // For each route
            for (FIRDocumentSnapshot *document in snapshot.documents) {
                RouteModel *route = [[RouteModel alloc] init];
                route.title = document.data[@"title"];
                route.color = document.data[@"color"];
                route.city = document.data[@"city"];

                [routes addObject:route];
            }

            [self.routesPageViewController setRoutes:routes];
        }
    }];


}
```

**And this is the called setRoutes method:**

```
- (void) setRoutes:(NSMutableArray<RouteModel *> *)routes {
    self.routes = routes;

    NSMutableArray<RoutePageViewController *> * routeViewControllers = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (RouteModel * route in routes) {
        [routeViewControllers addObject:[self viewControllerAtIndex:[routes indexOfObject:route]]];
    }

    [self setViewControllers:routeViewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

When the `setRoutes` method gets executed it throws the error in the image below, saying that it cannot dereference it:

[image]

The `setRoutes` methods gets executed inside a block.

**And I get this weird thread stack:**
[image]

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: where do you create routesPageViewController? how this property is defined?

Comment: in the `viewDidLoad` method I assign it to a weak nonatomic property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
- (void) setRoutes:(NSMutableArray<RouteModel *> *)routes {
    self.routes = routes;
```

invoking `self.routes` implicity calles the setter `setRoutes` which causes a recursive infinite calls as indicated by your stack.

Comment: Tnx. This solved the problem. But I have a new one now. ` 'The number of view controllers provided (2) doesn't match the number required (1) for the requested transition'`

Comment: It means that the page view controller requires only one view controller and the other view controllers must be added by using the page view controller's data source mechanism

Comment: I have implemented it

Comment: Ok, so now what you need to do is pass in the array only the first view controller that will be shown. The other view controllers you need to provide in the `pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:` and `pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:` methods of the datasource

Answer (score 1):

At the time the block is passed onto `getDocumentsWithCompletion` method is executed, `routes` array has already been deallocated and set to `nil` because no one is retaining it anywhere outside the block.

You should either move it into the block or declare it as a class property so it won't be thrown out of memory while class instance is alive.

```
[routesRef getDocumentsWithCompletion:^(FIRQuerySnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
    NSMutableArray<RouteModel*> *routes = [NSMutableArray array];
    ...
    [self.routesPageViewController setRoutes:routes];
}];
```

**After the update:**

Doing `self.routes = routes` invokes `setRoutes:` which in turn is causing a loop in your code. You should change it to:

```
- (void)setRoutes:(NSMutableArray<RouteModel *> *)routes {
  if (_routes != routes) {
    _routes = routes;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: `routes` can't be `nil` if you do what I proposed. App is probably crashing due to a different error. Maybe you might want to share more of your code?

Comment: I edited the question. It is nil when received in the `setRoutes` method

Comment: @TheoBouwman not necessarily. the crash is on the method signature line which means the entire view controller has been deallocated and you still try to access it